# JS library or CSS to achieve stacked card animation like advisable

Tags: javascript, css, animation, jquery

I am inspired by the live dynamic auto animated stacked card on [Advisable](https://advisable.com/)

Is there a JS library or CSS animation pack which I can use to achieve a similar result.

So far I have found [one library](https://github.com/junedchhipa/stacked-cards) which does something similar, but its not quite the same

Comment: Welcome on the SoftwareRecs SE! Your post looks a little bit spammy. Possibly it is not. I suggest to link example videos which does not look spammy, not even a little bit - the SE sites are very sensitive for that.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @peterh-ReinstateMonica. I have removed the video link. I am not affiliated with Advisable in any way. I am not sure how else to phrase this question.